# Awk scripting help

Tags: awk, text-processing

Hey guys new to scripting and looking to see why I get the following error message:

```
syntax error near unexpected token '$0'
```

using this `.sh` file to rearrange date and time in a `.txt` file so that certain characters are deleted.

I have a awk.sh file that contains:

```
Match ($0 /\[(0-9]+)\/([A-Z][a-z]+)\/([0-9]+)([0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]) \+[0-9]+\] matches)
printf("20%s 10%s 10%s 10%s\n",matches[1],matches[2],matches[3],matches[4])
```

Just not sure why I get this message

log.txt file contains:

```
hello.googlebot.com - [10/December/2012:04:14:15 +0100] "GET /plain.txt HTTP/1.0" 132 12 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

So what I'm trying to do is display the 2nd column (date and time) in the .txt file as:

```
10 December 2012 04:14:15
```

not as shown above, so pretty much get rid of the forward slashes, the colon in between the date and time and also remove the `+0100]`

Don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: It's hard to answer your question as posted - you appear to be trying to use `awk` commands inside a shell script - but don't seem to be actually calling the `awk` command interpreter. Can you give us some more context please?

Comment: Hi, yeh I'm trying to use awk commands inside a shell script.

I use the command in terminal:
cat log.txt | awk.sh -s2 | grep.december

to search for december in the whole file from a .txt file

I am trying to get info from another .txt file, specifically the date if i can.

Just keeps coming up with that error

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us an example of your input file and an example of your desired output. The way you are trying is very complex and your regular expression has syntax errors that make it impossible to understand what you are after. The command you gave in the previous comment also would not work, there's no such thing as `awk.sh -s2` (unless you have written another script that you're not showing) and `grep.december` is not a thing either.

Comment: Edited it,hopefully that makes more sense?

Comment: What exactly do you want to match _on_? Are you trying to find all such date stamps, or the date stamps of all instances of hello.googlebot.com?

Comment: Im simply trying to take the data from the log.txt file and change it to display the date ($2) in the format i have shown in terminal. Can that be done?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, to run `awk` scripts, you need to use the `awk` interpreter. You can either do it on the command line directly (`awk '{print $2}' file`), or you can create an awk script. What *is* needed is to somehow bring `awk` into the equation. You can't use the shell to run `awk` commands, only `awk` can do that.

In this case, the script is not really needed as steeldriver showed you but you can also do it the UNIX Way® and combine tools:

```
awk -F'[[ ]' '/hello.googlebot.com/{print $4}' log.txt | sed 's#:# #;s#/# #g'
```

#### Explanation

The `-F` option lets you choose the field separator, in this case, I am giving it a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) that contains two characters: `[` and  (space). This means that `awk` will split on those characters. The resulting fields will be:

```
1 : hello.googlebot.com
2 : -
3 : 
4 : 10/December/2012:04:14:15
```

I therefore print the 4th field, and pass it through [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) which just replaces the first `:` with a space (`s#:# #`) and all `/` with spaces (*all* because of the `g` in `s#/# #g`).

---

Alternatively, you could just switch to `perl` for the whole thing:

```
perl -pe 's/.*?\[(.+?)\s\S+\].*/$1/; s/:/ /; s#/# #g' log.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not clear *exactly* what you want to do, but probably the easiest approach would be via awk's substring substitution functions `sub` and/or `gsub` e.g.

```
awk '/hello.googlebot.com/ {gsub("[[/]"," ",$3); sub(":"," ",$3); print $3}' logfile
```

Remember that by default, awk splits on whitespace, so counting the spaces either side of the `-`, the date field is `$3` not `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `sed`,

```
sed '/hello.googlebot.com/ s/.* - \[\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\:\(.*\)\:\(.*\)\:\(.*\) .*\].*/\1 \2 \3 \4:\5:\6/g' file
```

**Example:**

```
$ echo 'hello.googlebot.com - [10/December/2012:04:14:15 +0100] "GET /plain.txt HTTP/1.0" 132 12 "-" "Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)"' | sed '/hello.googlebot.com/ s/.* - \[\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\/\(.*\)\:\(.*\)\:\(.*\)\:\(.*\) .*\].*/\1 \2 \3 \4:\5:\6/g'
10 December 2012 04:14:15
```